# Can someone tell me why my JQuery plugin doesn't work? I followed the steps carefully

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, debugging

I followed the steps here:  http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/10/29/jbar-a-jquery-notification-plugin/

I just want it to display a notification bar when on body load, but it's not working.

There is one thing I changed that's different than the tutorial.  I did `$(this).ready` on line 9 of the JQuery plugin.

Thanks!

**Edit: It binds to body ready perfectly. (notice the alert). It just doesn't show the bar.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
insertBefore($('.content'))
```

It seems to me that you are inserting your bar before something with the "content" class, but you don't have any element with that class.

Comment: Huh? What is that insertBefore? How do I apply that to my thing?

Comment: just caught that myself. working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/subhaze/a8xty/

Comment: How did you get that to work? I couldn't? How come it works for you but not me?

Comment: @TIMEX - you need to have DIV on top with class "content". If still no luck please edit your post with your full code and we'll see what you've done wrong.

Comment: `$('.content')` looks for any element on your page with the class "content".
`jQueryElement.insertBefore(givenElement)` inserts the jQueryElement into the document, just before the placeholder givenElement (in this case, the one you found with `$('.content')`).
You could allow the user to specify this placeholder element in the parameters, so it does not get hardcoded into your plugin.  (Users may have other elements with the "content" class, and that would be a conflict)

Answer (score 2):

There is no `$(this).ready()` in jQuery, unless `this` points to `document`.

Generally, you don't onDOMready things in your plugin - that is up to the person implementing your plugin to do.

Comment: So how do I fix this? What do I have to do?  It binds to body ready just fine.. the notification bar just won't show

Comment: @TIMEX Remove your onDOMReady stuff. Assume your plugin will be called after the DOM is ready.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the last comma in options.  The last option won't have a comma at the end.

Also, Wrap it in:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

});

Comment: I did that, but doesn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

Read the comments on the page where you got the plugin. It explains that the plugin, as written, only works on a button press (the element that you call .bar on needs to be a button).

Another comment also shows how you should be able to make it work the way you want:

*RAVI TOM SEPTEMBER 6TH, 2010 AT 10:10*

in html file change this line

```
$(“#msgup”).bar({
```

to

```
$(“body”).bar({
```

In jquery.bar.js file change the line number 9 to

```
$this.ready(function(e){
```

These changes will help you to show notification once page loads

Comment: I did that, but it doesn't work. It binds. But it doesn't display